# Show content after ends of animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I would like to make animation css with delay. The first div must hide, after ends of animation I would like to show my div. But my div hide after.

```css
#test p {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadein 2s linear 2s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s linear 2s;
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s linear 2s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-animation: fadein 2s linear 2s;
  /* Opera */
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  /* Firefox */
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadein {
  /* Opera */
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `forwards` (the `animation-fill-mode`) with the animation:

```css
#test p {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadein 2s linear 2s forwards;
  /*OR
    animation: fadein 2s linear 2s;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    */
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

As you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode):

> forwards
>
> The target will retain the computed values set by the **last**
>   **keyframe** encountered during execution.

Answer (score -1):

It seems removing the `linear 2s` following the `fadein 2s` allows this to work.

```
animation: fadein 2s;
-moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */
```

What were you attempting to accomplish with combining linear and fadein?

Comment: fadein is the name of the animation :) and linear is a timing function .. and 2 s is the delay .. i advise to read more about how animation works before posting such answer ...

Comment: Yeah, I did actually look into it before posting the answer, and fadein isn't defined on that page which is why I sought the clarification.  But note taken, I don't deny I still have lots to learn and am much more knowledgeable in some areas than others...

Comment: because fadein is the name of the animation defined by the OP ... look at his code and see how to define and run animation